# Persistent message queue with at-least-once delivery

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka

I have been looking at message queues (currently between Kafka and RabbitMQ) for one of my projects where these are biggest must have features.

Must have features

- Messages in queues should be persistent. (only until they are processed successfully by consumers.)
- Messages in queues should be removed only when downstream consumers were able to process the message successfully. Basically, a consumer should ACK. that it processed a message successfully.

Good to have features

- To increase throughput, consumers should be able to pull batch of messages from queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with `Kafka` it will only retains message for a configurable duration of time after which the messages will be discarded to free up spaces no matter consumed or not.

And it is simply the responsibilities of the Kafka consumers to keep a track of what has been consumed.

IMHO if you require to keep the messages persisted for ever than consider using a different storage medium (database may be).

Comment: Thanks. I edited my  question details to reflect the fact that "Messages should be persistent only until they are consumed successfully"

Comment: then you can definitely remove kafka from your list of choise .. it won't keep messages after the specifc time no matter consumed or not

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.